# <picture> tag does not show picture

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my `img` inside the `picture` tag does not want to show? Any ideas?

Thanks!

```html
<picture data-qa-node="picture" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
        <source srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.webp 1x, http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.webp 2x, http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.webp 3x" type="image/webp" data-qa-node="source"
        data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
            <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png 2x, http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png 3x" alt="Google"
            class="AppBlocksCarousel__image_2gZ2B" data-qa-node="img" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
    </picture>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image path is wrong. See my example

```html
<picture data-qa-node="picture" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
        <source srcset="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" type="image/webp" data-qa-node="source"
        data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
            <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png 2x, http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png 3x" alt="Google"
            class="AppBlocksCarousel__image_2gZ2B" data-qa-node="img" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
    </picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the image: (wrong url in `source` tag)

```html
<picture data-qa-node="picture" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
        <source srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" type="image/webp" data-qa-node="source"
        data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
            <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" alt="Google"
            class="AppBlocksCarousel__image_2gZ2B" data-qa-node="img" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
    </picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image you are looking is not available on this URL

```
http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png
```

Try this

```
<picture data-qa-node="picture" data-qa-file="AppBlocksCarousel">
            <source srcset="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" type="image/webp">
                <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" srcset="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png, http://diy logodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" alt="Google">
        </picture>
```